# Как скопировать элементы из xml не потеряв актуального значения xml:lang?

Tags: xml, c#, .net, vb.net

Вопрос к экспертам.

Есть xml:

```
<e1 xml:lang='en-us'><e2>Hello</e2></e1>
```

Есть второй xml:

```
<t1></t1>
```

Нужно используя .NET скопировать e2 в t1 так, чтобы e2 не потерял информацию о языке:

```
<t1><e2 xml:lang='en-us'>Hello</e2></t1>
```

Дело в том, что согласно стандарту XML [2.12 Language Identification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-lang-tag) значение xml:lang распространяется на подэлементы и по идеи при копировании оно должно сохраняться.
Хотелось бы узнать какое-нибудь готовое решение, которое есть в стандартных библиотека .NET, чтобы скопировать элемент без потери значения xml:lang.

Comment: Почему бы просто не получить текущий `xml:lang` у `e2` в первом документе через [`XPathNaviagator`](http://hashcode.ru/questions/260877/c-linq-to-xml-%D0%B8-xml-lang), сравнить с текущим `xml:lang` у `t1`, и добавить атрибут, если не совпадает?

Ну да, велосипед.

Comment: Пока я исхожу из того, что не всё знаю, поэтому ищу стандартные решения.  
Интересно, какое поведение в других библиотеках у java-ы или python-а?